# Multiple inputs in a Python Subprocess PIPE (with stdin or communicate)

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin, popen

I've been looking for an answer to the question above.

The Popen command should not return anything, its simply asking for "do you want to continue?" (yes) and the "admin password" taken from a local database.

Current code state is: Everything works fine but asks me the second input, first input passes through.

- I'm using an Ubuntu Server (with Python -u)
- Tried flushing after each stdin.write
- Tried communicate (Having problem with it, code loops unlimited times)
- Tried pexpect but also having problems with it too, Popen is more suitable under my conditions I guess.

So, I'm open to suggestions and willing to try your helps. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        #Input 1
        p = Popen(["foo", "bar"], stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        try:
            p.stdin.write('yes' + linesep)
        except IOError as e:
            if e.errno == errno.EPIPE or e.errno == errno.EINVAL:
                break
            else:
                raise
        p.stdin.flush()
        #Input 2
        try:
            p.stdin.write(KeyPass + linesep)
        except IOError as e:
            if e.errno == errno.EPIPE or e.errno == errno.EINVAL:
                break
            else:
                raise
        p.stdin.flush()
        p.stdin.close()
        p.wait()
```

Comment: If you're trying to drive an interactive app, `Popen` is not more suitable for your conditions than `pexpect`. Show us what you tried and what went wrong; it's almost certain to be an easier fix.

Comment: Also, it's asking for 'the "admin password" taken from a local database'. Often when programs ask for a password, they either read from the TTY instead of stdin, or refuse to proceed if stdin isn't a TTY or can't be set to NOECHO, or call `libpam` or similar instead of reading it themselves. If you run this on the command line, does the password echo when you enter it? (Also, the fact that you're not reading stdout, and therefore not waiting for the prompt before sending the password, will break it if it discards input before the prompt, which many password inputs do.)

Comment: Even the yes input sent, you cant see anything but it works, you can try anything else then it does not ask for admin password. I dont want to see anything either, I wont print the inputs or outputs when my work is done, I'm debugging for now. Also the admin password is parsed from a XML database using minidom. So it is set to KeyPass variable. I do not know the details you've talking about I'm sorry. Its a simple app and popen should suffice.

Comment: Again, when you run the app for the command line, does it echo the password or not? And if you start typing before the prompt, does it ignore whatever you typed before the prompt or not?

Comment: Its all like changing password of the *nix system. It does not echo the password neither asterisks. Sorry for the misunderstanding in my first comment.

Comment: Just use `pexpect`. To understand why, read the first reason in [Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> its simply asking for "do you want to continue?" (yes) and the "admin password"

To answer `"yes"` if the child process asks *"...continue?"* and to write a password when prompted:

```
import pexpect # $ pip install pexpect

output, status = pexpect.run('foo bar',
    events={r'continue\?': 'yes\n', 'password': 'p4$$W__rd\n'},
    withexitstatus=1)
```

`pexpect` makes sure that even if the child process writes/reads directly to/from a terminal (outside process' stdout/stdin), you'll see its output and it receives your input.

Comment: For those of you using Windows, `run()` will not work. It relies on Unix pseudoterminals. As of version 4, the [documentation](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#pexpect-on-windows) suggests using [pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/popen_spawn.html#pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn) (which is experimental).

Comment: @AndrewMyers OP uses Ubuntu. Pexpect hadn't supported Windows at all at the time of the answer.  `PopenSpawn` won't help if the program reads the password from the console directly (getwch/ReadConsole API — Windows analog of working with a pty).

Answer (score 1):

> It does not echo the password neither asterisks.

This means you can't drive it through `stdin`. What you're trying to do is just not possible that way.

See if there's another way to give it a password—maybe on the command line, or through the environment—or to avoid giving it a password (e.g., with `ssh` you can exchange keys instead of passing passwords).

If not, your only option is to give it a pseudo-TTY instead of a regular pipe. (Even this isn't guaranteed to work, but it's likely to work, and worth trying.)

There are three ways to do that from Python: [`os.openpty`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.openpty), [`os.forkpty`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.forkpty), and the [`pty`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pty.html#module-pty) module. In theory, `forkpty` is the most platform-specific, but in practice, because `pty` is only tested on Linux, and `openpty` requires you to do other platform-specific stuff to actually do anything useful with it, I'd start with `forkpty`. The code looks like this:

```
pid, fd = os.forkpty()
if not pid:
    # We're in the child here, but we still have to launch the program
    os.execlp('foo', 'bar')
# This code is still in the parent.
```

Now, the parent can use `os.read(fd)` and `os.write(fd)` to talk to the child, and the child will see it as coming from the TTY. And when the child is done, you have to `os.waitpid(pid)` it. Just remember that you're dealing with low-level file I/O here—no decoding to Unicode, no universal newlines, and, most of all, no buffering. This can be tricky to deal with, but you have to deal with it.

Or, of course, you can use a library like `pexpect`, which can use a PTY and hide all the details from you. I'm not sure why you're resistant to this idea, but when you get frustrated trying to deal with `forkpty`, maybe give it another chance.

Comment: I should try pexpect again and then get back to this.

Comment: Finally after working with pexpect for several hours, I managed it. Thank you abarnert.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `communicate()` instead of `write()`

```
p.communicate(input='{}\n{}'.format('yes', KeyPass).encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: it won't work otherwise the code in the question would work. It is likely that  the password is read from the terminal directly. See [Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)